# Pandas `pivot_table` working with `decimal.Decimal` type

Tags: python, pandas, types, decimal, pivot-table

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
date        id      value           type
2021-01-02  123123   0.3           apple
2021-01-02  123123  2.05           banana
2021-01-02  456456  2.01819        apple
2021-01-02  456456  606800000      banana
2021-01-02  567567  2.2            apple
2021-01-02  891891  2475368        banana
........
```

Where the datatype for column `value` is `decimal.Decimal`.

My expected result looks like this:

```
date        id       apple         banana
2021-01-02  123123   0.3           2.05
2021-01-02  456456   2.01819       606800000
2021-01-02  567567   2.2           NaN
2021-01-02  891891   Nan           2475368
```

I tried to use `pandas.pivot_table`:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df,
                          values='value',
                          index=['date', 'id'],
                          columns='type').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

This gave me result (with only the first two columns):

```
date        id
2021-01-02  123123 
2021-01-02  456456  
2021-01-02  567567  
2021-01-02  891891  
...
```

Does anyone what's going on here? Why I only got two columns? Thanks.

Update:
I saw the comments and answers saying can't reproduce the dataframe with two columns, that's so weird, is it because I'm using an older verion of pandas? I still only got two columns...I'm using `Python3.8` + `pandas==1.3.0`

Below is my result:

[image]

I managed to get the expected result by using pandas `1.3.3`.

Comment: shouldn't the second line have banana instead on apple? 2021-01-02  123123  2.05           apple

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, I've updated the question, thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Your code gives me 4 columns (date, id, apple, banana) with the correct values as in your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, I can't reproduce your issue.

My setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from decimal import Decimal


data = {'date': [Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00')],
               'id': [123123, 123123, 456456, 456456, 567567, 891891],
               'value': [Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875'),
                Decimal('2.04999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875'),
                Decimal('2.018190000000000150492951433989219367504119873046875'),
                Decimal('606800000'),
                Decimal('2.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125'),
                Decimal('2475368')],
               'type': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Pivot:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df,
                          values='value',
                          index=['date', 'id'],
                          columns='type').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        date      id    apple       banana
0 2021-01-02  123123  1.17500          NaN
1 2021-01-02  456456  2.01819  606800000.0
2 2021-01-02  567567  2.20000          NaN
3 2021-01-02  891891      NaN    2475368.0
```

Comment: So weird, can I ask which version of pandas you're using? I still only got two columns...I'm using `Python3.8` + `pandas==1.3.0`

Comment: `Python 3.9.7` and `Pandas 1.3.3`. If you use my setup, does the problem remain?

Comment: Ha I upgraded pandas to `1.3.3`, still using `Python 3.8`, and I got the expected result! I wonder why is that...did they change anything in the new version? From the doc:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html It seems like nothing changes from `1.3.0` to `1.3.3`....

Comment: I also didn't find in Changelog: [1.3.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.1.html), [1.3.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.2.html) and [1.3.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting 4 columns with your code
I'm running:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
print(pd.__version__)
print(sys.version)
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df,
                          values='value',
                          index=['date', 'id'],
                          columns='type').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(pivot_df.to_string())
```

Output

```
1.0.3
3.7.7 (default, Apr 15 2020, 05:09:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
         date      id    apple        banana
0  2021-01-02  123123  0.30000  2.050000e+00
1  2021-01-02  456456  2.01819  6.068000e+08
2  2021-01-02  567567  2.20000           NaN
3  2021-01-02  891891      NaN  2.475368e+06
```

Comment: Hi I still have two missing columns, just wondering which version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I'm running 1.0.3

Comment: I used pandas `1.3.0` and got two missing fields, but `1.3.3` works fine. I didn't downvote your answer, thanks.